# Frame Animation fails with more than 5 frames - 240dpi

Tags: android, animation, frame

I have a frame animation with 135 frames that should swap 25 times per second. The frames are 700X1000 pixels with 240 dpi. The problem I have is that whenever I define in the XML animation file more than 5 frames the application crashes. The frames are found in the drawable folder. I tried copying them to the drawable-xhdpi but this did not solve the problem.

Thanks,
Simon

Comment: post your logcat error messages here..

Comment: E/dalvikvm(29406): Out of memory: Heap Size=65571KB, Allocated=61893KB, Limit=65536KB
E/dalvikvm(29406): Extra info: Footprint=63459KB, Allowed Footprint=65571KB, Trimmed=0KB
D/skia(29406): --- decoder->decode returned false
W/dalvikvm(29406): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4163c2d0)
E/AndroidRuntime(29406): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(29406): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
E/AndroidRuntime(29406):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3608)
E/AndroidRuntime(29406):  at android.view.View.performClick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem that loading images consumes all heap memory (memory that has your application avaliable) which is 32MB or 64MB. Images are loaded in on heap as Bitmap in ARGB - 4 bytes per pixel. Try to subsample animation images. Your animation has 135*700*1000*4 bytes = 360.5 MB.

You can use method *decodeResource* with BitmapFactory.Options opts that has parameter [inSampleSize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize) where you can set subsampling of image. Also parameter [inPreferredConfig](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inPreferredConfig) can be used to set RGB_565 instead of ARGB_8888 in case when you don't need transparency in images.

Answer (score 1):

The error clearly says that you are trying to use more memory. This directly points to the image sizes. So, you need to resize your images to use lesser memory. One which can be used for this reason is [BitmapFactory.Option](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize). Or else go with manually resizing your images take care that it suit all your needs.

> Heap size is the amount of memory allocated to an application to
>   execute.
>   The heap size for android applications are determined by the device
>   RAM.  For example if the device has RAM of 179 MB, the android
>   applications will only get the heap size of 18MB.

Find about it more [here](http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Memory-Optimization-2040.php). more on how to Load Large Bitmaps Efficiently is found [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).

Answer (score 0):

As the stack trace says, it's causing OutOfMemory error.
Since the frames are with higher resolution and no.of frames are also more, it's giving this exception.